# Error: Not a recognized resampling method

Tags: r, resampling, imbalanced-data

I'm having trouble to run my model to balancing my dataframe. It's showing me that you didn't recognize the resampling method. What do I do?

```
> # Criando funcao controle para o treino
> ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeateadcv",
+                      number = 10,
+                      repeats = 5,
+                      summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
+                      classProbs = TRUE)
Warning message:
`repeats` has no meaning for this resampling method. 

> # Construindo modelo padrao de classificacao usando GBM
> model1 <- train(is_attributed ~ .,
+                 data = df1,
+                 method = "gbm",
+                 verbose = FALSE,
+                 metric = "ROC",
+                 trControl = ctrl)
Error: Not a recognized resampling method.
```

Answer (score 1):

Trouble is on hyperparameter *method*. Is "repeatedcv", not "repeateadcv", without *a*.